# permission denied-public key while running a shell script which contains ansible command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ansible

I have an shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello world"

ansible zookservers -i /home/ec2-user/kafka_scripts/ansible_rep/inventory -a "/home/ec2-user/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/config/server.properties" --sudo
```

---

my error was

```
 | FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
    while connecting to 172.30.0.243:22
```

when I run the ansible command then it is executing
but when I kept it inside a shell script I am getting the above error

my shell is with chmod 777 permission - so the problem it not with shell execution permission

I found something interesting
when I run the script from any other place I'm getting error. but when run it in ansible directory then it is executed. 
later when I run it from any other directory it is not throwing any error. 
so the problem is with initial public key authentication

Comment: And you're not calling the script with sudo? That's the only idea I would have why your key gets ignored. Call Ansible with `-vvv` to debug ssh.

Comment: Hi I tried that but I am unable to solve the problem --  ' FAILED => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
    while connecting to 172.30.0.243:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.'

Comment: I found something intersting -- when I run the script from any other place I'm getting error. but when run it in ansible directory then it is executed and later when I run it from any other directory it is not throwing any error. so the problem is with initial public key authentication--glad if you can help me in this way

Comment: Do you have a custom ansible.cfg with special ssh settings in that "ansible directory"?

Comment: yes ansible.cfg file with ssh username and aws private key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found something intersting -- when I run the script from any other place I'm getting error. but when run it in ansible directory then it is executed

The problem most likely is the location of your `ansible.cfg`. Ansible will use the config from one of these locations (from the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html)):

- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
- ansible.cfg (in the **current** directory)
- .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

First match wins.

So it uses the config from the "ansible directory", if called **from** there. If called from any other location there is no ansible.cfg in that directory. Since this is where you have stored you username and private key location the authentication fails.

The best solution seems to be to utilize the environment variable `ANSIBLE_CONFIG`. Just store the path to your ansible.cfg in there. I think it is `/home/ec2-user/kafka_scripts/ansible_rep/ansible.cfg`, right?

You can set that variable in your script.

```
ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/home/ec2-user/kafka_scripts/ansible_rep/ansible.cfg ansible zookservers -i /home/ec2-user/kafka_scripts/ansible_rep/inventory -a "/home/ec2-user/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/config/server.properties" --sudo
```